# Converting WebSphere Portal application to standard Java EE application

Tags: java, migration, portlet, portal, websphere-portal

I have to convert a WebSphere portal application to a standard web application which can be deployed to WebSphere itself for now (and to JBoss later).

How can I find what built-in portal features are being used?

I have full code access. Are there any tools for this? What are the things I should consider?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how the application has been developed and which version of the portlet spec your application was built against.

If we take the case of porting a single portlet to a standard J2EE where the latest portlet spec is used the application might be using more modern practices e.g. be using resourceURLs and Ajax calls from JS to communicate  with the backend.

This is the best case scenario, where you can take the JSP remove the portlet specific stuff e.g. the context roots and portlet name spaces. Then convert your resourceURLs into servlets by creating servlets which either call the same service methods or depending on how the code was written taken the code straight for the serveResource methods in the Portlet class.

Now worst case scenario for porting, this is where the portlet makes heavy use of actionURLs and other portal features which are very specific to the portlet spec. I'd guess that the best way of going about porting these is to try emulate the behavior of the portlet. You could try to hold all of your state information on the backend like a portlet does and replace these actionURLs/renderURLs with JSPs/servlets appropriately while having some object on the backend which stores the current state of the page for each user.

Hope this helps, more information on your project would obviously make it easier to help.

In regards to finding out what portlet specific features have been used look at the portlet class' imports and the tags used in the JSP along with the portlet.xml

Comment: No problem, sorry it wasn't a more full answer but very difficult to give in these circumstances.